# byRole is not returning the DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I am migrating some of my unit test cases which were previously written using Jest and Enzyme to React Testing Library. I am using Material UI's `Select` component and I know that, in order to open the dropdown, we have to trigger the `mouseDown` event on the corresponding `div`. Here is how I did it in Enzyme (working):

```
wrapper.find('[role="button"]').simulate('mousedown', { button: 0 });
```

I am trying to achieve the same using React Testing Library in the following manner, which is not working:

```
const { container, getAllByRole, getByRole } = renderComponent(mockProps);
fireEvent.mouseDown(getByRole('button')); // trigger the mouseDown on div having role=button
```

After this I am trying to access the `listbox` element which is `ul` element:

```
getByRole('listbox')
```

which throws an error and says:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "listbox"

There are no accessible roles. But there might be some inaccessible roles. If you wish to access them, then set the `hidden` option to `true`. Learn more about this here: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#byrole
```

I have verified and the `ul` element is visible (neither it nor its parent have display none or visibility hidden)

[image]

**UPDATE - 1**

I have tried all the following approach to wait for element to appear in DOM:

- `waitFor`
- `findByRole` instead of `getByRole`

in both the case it throws error that
`Unable to find role="listbox"`

What is wrong?

Comment: `getByRole('listbox')` The role of the element is `listbox`?

Comment: @Kapobajza Yes. Its the `ul` element which has the `role="listbox"`

Comment: Okay, I thought maybe that it was a typo. What you could try is to use `await findByRole('listbox')`, because when you trigger an event which is supposed to show/hide an element you have to wait for that element to show up in your DOM. But I am not entirely sure if `findByRole` will work

Comment: Yup, I tried that as well, but no luck. I will update the question with more example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root cause of this issue. I am using the `Select` component from MUI in `disablePortal` mode, which make the menu list to be rendered inside the parent component instead of document body. But while MUI does that, it doesn't remove the `aria-hidden` attribute from the parent component's `div`, and because of that testing library is not able to locate the `listbox` (ul) element inside.

There is an issue reported here:
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/19450

So as a work around, I passed the `data-testid` to the `menu` component (`MenuListProps`) and using it to get the `listbox`.

Answer (score 2):

If the element is not accessible at the first render this error could appear, you can try passing the option hidden to the options key in the second argument of the getByRole, if this not works you can try using findByRole, that method wait for the element, and if you want to be sure of the visibility of the element you can try adding a waitFor inside of the test.

```
getByRole('listbox', { options: { hidden: true } });
```

Comment: No, that is the idea, we don't want to access the hidden element. On firing the mouseDown event, the hidden elements are visible but still I am not able to access them. and Yes findByRole is also not working.. which is weird

Answer (score 0):

Make sure animations are not compromising your results. If the animations change opacity or display and they did not finish before assertion from jest... it is likely to throw an error.

Comment: Any idea how to handle that ?

Comment: For example wait for a timeout before doing the assertion:

```await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 350));```

Comment: Yeah.. I tried that as well.. no luck

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox or fiddle so we better help?